# How can I use splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory on flutter default app bar back button?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use `splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory` on flutter default app bar back button?

Comment: You want to remove splash(InkWell) in back button in the `AppBar`?

Comment: @PrinceSanjivy yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this to your `AppBar`

```
AppBar(
        leading: Navigator.canPop(context)
            ? IconButton(
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              )
            : null,
      )
```

Overriding the exisitng appBar icon by using `leading` property and removing the splash.